# Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class - Only on Gingerbread with ActionbarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, navigation-drawer, android-2.3-gingerbread, inflate-exception

I've been stumped on this issue for a couple days now and I'm losing my hair.  I scoured through pages upon pages of questions on-line and haven't found an answer so hoping for some help!  I have an Android 4.0 app with a main activity that has a Navigation Drawer - and it works fine.  Depending on the menu item chosen, I load either a Fragment or ListFragment.  Again this works fine.

Now, I'm trying to provide support for Gingerbread using ActionbarSherlock.  I updated my main activity and the code to use the ABS libraries, but I'm now getting an error only on my version 2.3 emulator!  The updated code still works fine on 4.0+!

I get the following error: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class  on my activity_main.xml

Maybe I've been staring at this too long but I can't understand why it works for ICS and up but not for Gingerbread!  Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Here is my code:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

strings.xml snippet:

```
<!-- Nav Drawer Menu Items -->
<string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
    <item>Frag 1</item>
    <item>Frag 2</item>
    <item>Frag 3</item>
    <item>Frag 4</item>
</string-array>

<!-- Nav Drawer List Item Icons -->
<!-- Keep them in order as the titles are in -->
<array name="nav_drawer_icons">
    <item>@drawable/ic_nav_drawer_frag1</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_nav_drawer_frag2</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_nav_drawer_frag3</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_nav_drawer_frag4</item>
</array>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Fragment 1
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Fragment 2
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Fragment 3
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Fragment 4
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(3, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                    // accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                    // accessibility
        ) { 
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for item list
            // displayView(startingFragment);
            displayView(startingFragment);
        }
    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else { 
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
            menu.getItem(i).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Intent intent;
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        SherlockFragment fragment = null;
        SherlockListFragment listFragment = null;
        Bundle bundle = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0: // Fragment 1
            listFragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
        case 1: // Fragment 2
            listFragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        case 2: // Fragment 3
            listFragment = new Fragment3();
            break;
        case 3: // Fragment 4
            fragment = new Fragment4();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if ((fragment != null) || (listFragment != null)) {
            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            } else if (listFragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, listFragment).commit();
            }

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

I've also updated the manifest to use android:minSdkVersion="8" and android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"

Stack Trace:

```
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446): FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class <unknown> 
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at ca.brainservice.pricecruncher.free.util.NavDrawerListAdapter.getView(NavDrawerListAdapter.java:47)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1290)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1588)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:714)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  ... 35 more
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x2 
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2108)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:344)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:337)
04-26 19:18:26.092: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  ... 38 more
```

Comment: did u solve this issue ??? I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment yet, but I noticed you're using `invalidateOptionsMenu()` instead of `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`. I'm not sure if this will fix your problem yet, but that does look wrong.